# Как реализовать Таблицу Шульте используя Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Читал, что можно использовать dataGridView, но разобраться со всем не получилось.

```
if(datagrid.rows[e.RowIndex].cells[e.ColumnIndex].value.toString()==hod)
{
datagrid.rows[e.RowIndex].cells[e.ColumnIndex].value = "нашел";
hod++
if(hod==10)
{
messageBox.Show("Ты справился, твой результат"+time+");
}
```

Comment: Вы просто закинулм сюда какую то тему. Нет ни описания конкретной проблемы, ни ваших попыток самому разобраться, ни ожидаемого результата. Ознакомьтесь с руководством [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @tym32167, Была попытка работать с кодом, который я нашел в просторах интернета.

Comment: @tym32167, Вот этот код был на сайте, как там писал автор статьи, нужно создать таблицу 5x5 и заполнить числами

Comment: Еще раз прошу прощения за плохо оформленный вопрос, буду меняться

Comment: убрал свой минус с вас. Поясните, что ваша таблица должна делать и какие у вас конкретно проьблемы с кодом?

Comment: @tym32167, Таблица Шульте - таблица случайно расположенных чисел, обычно размером 5x5 элементов и обычно состоит из цифр и букв.
Т.к у меня  еще есть время, для начала я бы хотел реализовать таблицы 3x3,5x5 из цифр и еще 3x3,5x5 из букв. [ссылка]https://cepia.ru/speedreading/schulte/ - пример таблицы. Сложность возникает в том, что я не могу понять, как правильно ее реализовать и что использовать для ее реализации, хотя из кода выше, кажется,что все понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сгенерировать таблицу со случайными занчениями очень просто

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    DataGridView gv;
    Random random = new Random();

    public MyForm()
    {       
        gv = new DataGridView()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ReadOnly = true,
            AllowUserToAddRows = false,
            AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
        };

        FillGrid(gv,5,5);
        this.Controls.Add(gv);
    }   

    private void FillGrid(DataGridView gv, int width, int height)
    {
        gv.ColumnCount = width;
        var count = height * width;
        var stack = new Stack<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, count).OrderBy(x=>random.Next(1, count)));

        gv.Rows.Add(height);

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                gv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = stack.Pop();            
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
new MyForm().ShowDialog();
```

Результат

[image: ...]

Comment: Благодарю! Код, вроде не большой, буду разбираться. С буквами, точно так же или там нужно по другому реализовать?